# Android get restarted once it is connected or disconnected to bluetooth device

Tags: android, bluetooth

Android mobile app always get restarted once it is connected or disconnected to bluetooth device. what something else i need to comment ? tell me.

Comment: You don't need to comment anything. But it would help you to take a look at your logcat and see what crashes, if it crashes. We can't guess what you did wrong, but you must have done something wrong as many other bluetooth apps work just fine.

Comment: show your code that crashes

Comment: ok, i got the same problem. following is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734849/android-mobile-app-always-get-restarted-once-it-is-connected-or-disconnected-to

Comment: Hi，@323go . i still go wrong. according above solution. you can see youtube, has same situation.

Comment: Hi @SidleCiel can you find solution for this issue.. ?

Answer (score 14):

This is by design. Android restarts (recreates) activity in case of any configuration change event to ensure app adapt to the new situation:
[Handling Runtime Changes - API Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)
Bluetooth connect/disconnect is similar configuration change event like orientation change, hard or soft keyboard change.
You can avoid app restart by handling configuration change event in your app:

add `android:configChanges = "keyboard|keyboardHidden"` attribute into your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
```

and implement `onConfigurationChanged()` method in your activity:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

See excellent answers here:

- [Bluetooth keyboard will cause activity destroy and recreate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735227/bluetooth-keyboard-will-cause-activity-destroy-and-recreate)
- [How to detect orientation change in layout in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726657/how-to-detect-orientation-change-in-layout-in-android)
- [orientation|keyboardHidden not calling onConfigurationChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656255/orientationkeyboardhidden-not-calling-onconfigurationchanged)
- [Is there a way to tell if the soft-keyboard is shown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457486/is-there-a-way-to-tell-if-the-soft-keyboard-is-shown/5457919#5457919)

Comment: "See excellent answers here:" this was an excellent answer:) I was missing "keyboard" flag! Thanks

Comment: Thank you sooooooo much. wasted a day and a half on this

Comment: Your a Godsent! thank you so much +1, must be marked as answer!

Answer (score 1):

Resurrecting an old topic, there are some bluetooth devices that - for some unapparent reason - also make other configuration changes besides the keyboard ones.
In this case, try to add in your Manifest, in the desired activity, the line:

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation"
```

That might be enough!

I also recommend taking a look at
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#config, in the subtopic **android:configChanges**.
Listed there are all the configuration changes a device can make.